# R, how to group by row value? Split?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, split

I have a dataframe with a vector in the follwing format
I want to keep all rows, within the "START" and "STOP" values in the column **val** (including them), and remove rows  that is not inside **start-stop**

```
id = str_c("x",1:20)
val = c(rep("NO1", 3), "START", rep("yes1", 3), "STOP", 
    "NO2", "START", rep("yes2", 3), "STOP", rep("NO3",6))
data = data.frame(id,val)
```

My expected output is

```
data = data.frame(id = c(str_c("x", 4:8), str_c("x", 10:14)),
              val = c("START", rep("yes1", 3), "STOP",
                      "START", rep("yes2", 3), "STOP"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the index of `'START'` and `'STOP'` values and create a sequence between them with `mapply` and select those rows from `data`.

```
ind1 <- which(data$val == 'START')
ind2 <- which(data$val == 'STOP')

data[sort(unique(unlist(mapply(`:`, ind1, ind2)))), ]

#    id   val
#4   x4 START
#5   x5  yes1
#6   x6  yes1
#7   x7  yes1
#8   x8  STOP
#10 x10 START
#11 x11  yes2
#12 x12  yes2
#13 x13  yes2
#14 x14  STOP
```

Comment: Thats great. Exactly what i needed.

Comment: Note that you need to guarantee that each start has an equal stop or it will recycle indices.

Comment: I am facing that exact situation. in my DF i have sometimes two STARTS (or STOPS) occurring.  I want to account from first START (when two STARTs are read before END) or, till   last END (when two END is read). Overall, the number of START and END are not equal

Comment: @SriRam I think you should ask this as a new question with the new conditions since your example didn't include such condition nor did you mention it. Changing the question now would invalidate the answers which are already posted here and would confuse future readers.

Comment: @RonakShah Hi, I have tried to put the maximum details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619727/r-how-to-group-by-split-or-subset-by-row-values . Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your data you could just do a brute force solution using a true false switch. You can return the row id's instead of the dataframe subset in the return output if you want.

```
parse_dataframe <- function(df, colnm='val'){
  idx = c()
  start <- FALSE
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if (df[i, colnm] == 'START') start <- TRUE
    if (start) idx <- c(idx, i)
    if (df[i, colnm] == 'STOP') start <- FALSE
  }
  return(df[idx, ])
}

parse_dataframe(data)
#    id   val
#4   x4 START
#5   x5  yes1
#6   x6  yes1
#7   x7  yes1
#8   x8  STOP
#10 x10 START
#11 x11  yes2
#12 x12  yes2
#13 x13  yes2
#14 x14  STOP
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The original Dataset contains about million records. I was looking for an 'R way' of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> data %>% mutate(ID = substr(val, nchar(val), nchar(val))) %>% 
+   mutate(ID = case_when(ID == 'T' ~ lead(ID), ID == 'P' ~ lag(ID), TRUE ~ ID)) %>% 
+   group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(c('START','STOP') %in% val)) %>% 
+   filter(row_number() %in% (which(val == 'START'): which(val == 'STOP'))) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-3)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   id    val  
   <chr> <chr>
 1 x4    START
 2 x5    yes1 
 3 x6    yes1 
 4 x7    yes1 
 5 x8    STOP 
 6 x10   START
 7 x11   yes2 
 8 x12   yes2 
 9 x13   yes2 
10 x14   STOP
```